# find pitches per frame from audio vector using Python

Tags: python, signals, signal-processing, librosa, pitch

I'm working on audio analysis project, my input audio  `y` has been converted to audio vectors, output of `y`:

```
array([-0.00085973, -0.00062583, -0.00042983, ...,  0.00038916,
       0.00024691,  0.00010018], dtype=float32)
```

I have used those parameters for detection:
Signal length =357454, Sampling Rate= 44100, Hop size=512, Frame size=2048

I used the `librosa.autocorrelation` for pitch detection but it gave me the correlation for whole input signal.
I tried to segment my input signal and get the pitch, I got the following error:

```
signal=y1
sampleRate = 44100
frameSize = 2048
hop = 512
length=len(y1)


pitch = []
start, stop = 0, 512
while stop <= length:
            f0 = y1[start:stop]
            autocorr = librosa.core.autocorrelate(f0)
            peaks = find_peaks(autocorr) 
            lag = peaks 
            pitch1 = sampleRate / lag 
            pitch.append(pitch1)
            start, stop = stop, stop + 512
            
print(np.array(pitch))
print(len(pitch))
```

error output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-951880997936> in <module>
     13             peaks = find_peaks(autocorr) # Find peaks of the autocorrelation
     14             lag = peaks # Choose the first peak as our pitch component lag
---> 15             pitch1 = sampleRate / lag # Transform lag into frequency
     16             pitch.append(pitch1)
     17             start, stop = stop, stop + 512

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

I'm new to Python, is there any other way to get pitch per frame?
Thank you.

Comment: I assume in line 14 where you say "Choose the first peak as our pitch component lag", you actually want to get the first item like `lag = peaks[0]`?